# Eloquent doesn't retrive the belongsTo relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a publication model which belongs to an author represented by the user model. This is how they are defined :

```
class Publication extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
  public $incrementing = false;

  public function author() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
  }
}
```

I used the standard naming conventions in my tables, so in the publications table I have a column nammed `user_id`.

```
class User extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
  const ROLES = ["Enseignant-Chercheur", "Doctorant"];

  public $incrementing = false;

  public function publications() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Publication');
  }
}
```

When I try to retrive my data :

```
$publications = \App\Models\Publication::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
die('<pre>'.var_export($publications[0], true).'</pre>');
```

The relations array is empty... In the database, the row is correctly filled with the right user id.
How to fix this ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? get the publications of a user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Wizix You can try as below to retrieve relationship data using explicitly define foreign key if your foreign key not match with laravel mechanism.

//in Publication Model define relationship as below

```
public function author() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User','user_id');
 }
```

// in user model define as below

```
public function publications() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Publication','user_id');
    //user_id consider as foriegn key in publication model's table
 }
```

then you can try accessing relationship data using "with" keyword using eloquent as below.

```
\App\Models\Publication::with('author')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: I had to explicity define my foreign key... I don't know why but it's working

Comment: @Wizix laravel try to map foreign key based on model name with appending '_id' if it not match then we need to define explicitly. for more details refer : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 3):

The relationship is loaded only if explicitly accessed, i.e.: `$publications[0]->author`

Or if you want you can [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) authors, and reduce the needed queries, with the function with():

```
\App\Models\Publication::with('author')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
```